Reorder the columns and rows of matrix table in power bi
I have a data in my matrix table. I have data in my column and row which is in alphabetical order, but I need to reorder the rows and the columns in my power bi desktop which is not in the alphabetical order.How do I reorder the matrix rows and columns?

Here in my table I need to reorder the rows where I need the rows order like
Ford
Suzuki
Toyota
BMW
Maruthi
Audi
Volvo  and columns order like
p1800   Celica  Creta HT kp800 Mustang M1

when you sort it on brand, it will automatically get sorted by alphabetic order.
maybe try sorting it on values, like 1964, 1968, 1970 so on...

You need to create another column in your data with the sort order and then sort by that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Yeah tried this link but I am not getting the option to sort by column in my power bi desktop. I have connected my report to the dataset which is not allowing me to edit the columns in the desktop.

You need to do it in the dataset you're connecting to...
